# How does one simulate the old unix grep -S strict functionality in linux

Tags: linux, centos, grep

I am grepping the output of a command and I wish to only return specific, strict results.

I remember some iteration of grep had a strict option `-s`/`--strict`.

For example, `grep -s bytes` would only return entries which mentioned the word "bytes" and not every word that *contains* bytes, like "megabytes", "kilobytes", etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
>    -w, --word-regexp
>           Select  only those lines containing matches that form whole
>           words.  The test is that the matching
>           substring must either be at the beginning of the line, or 
>           preceded  by  a  non-word  constituent
>           character.   Similarly,  it  must be either at the end of the
>           line or followed by a non-word con-
>           stituent character.  Word-constituent characters are
>           letters, digits, and the underscore.
> ```

Comment: Fantastic, sir.  I salute you and your thorough grep knowledge. :)

Comment: yes, my ability to run "man grep" and search for "word" is, indeed, the stuff of legend =)